Is there a version of proof theory that explicitly deals with concepts rather than text?
Proof theory is pretty explicit about the fact that is dealing with mere symbols. For example, they go out of their way to distinguish language variables from schema variables that represent formulas, and this in turn means that they often have to rely on axiom schemas rather than simple axioms.
Logic wasn't always this way. Before modern proof theory (or maybe before Hilbert), most logicians seemed to think that they were dealing with ideas or concepts rather than mere symbols on paper. They would have interpreted the inference rule
From A, A->B infer B.
not as a manipulation of symbols but as a notation to say something like "If you know that A and you know that A implies B, then you can infer that B". Here, A and B are propositions in the sense of ideas or concepts, not in the sense of formulas.
Has anyone tried to present proof theory from this basis?
ADDENDUM:
I wasn't clear, but one of the advantages of this sort of methodology is that you don't need extra machinery to explain why the rules of inference or the axioms are interesting. For example, modus ponens is interesting because it is clearly a valid form of reasoning, but once you reduce it to symbols, it becomes meaningless. Then you need additional semantic explanations or model theory to bring it back to the conceptual rule that it is intended to encode.

I'm sure things could be rewritten in that form, but compactness and readability would suffer. Symbolic notations are, essentially, a form of technical jargon. They exist because they express the ideas with maximum clarity and in minimum space. They can certainly be expanded into the conceptual forms, but that will turn one page of derivation into many, and for anyone who knows the symbols will be less readable rather than more. If you want it discussed in words, I would suggest looking at the textbooks or lecture notes which introduce these symbols and decide if that is really an improvement.


they often have to rely on axiom schemas rather than simple axioms. === Yeah, but so what though, if the Universe is well-defined and the inference rules are valid?  The generated objects can be concepts. The love between two people. Or anything else. They don't have to be textual, sequential, symbolic, or even enumerable. This isn't number theory! === What is it that your new model would do that can't be done in n-order predicate  calculus? === But keep Godel out of it!


The difference was the subject of the dispute in the early days of mathematical logic reflected in the Frege-Hilbert correspondence:"A mathematical theory, for Frege, has a particular subject-matter: number theory is about the natural numbers; geometry is about figures in space; and so on. Frege takes it that the sentences we use in mathematics are important only because of the nonlinguistic propositions (or, as he puts it, the “thoughts”) they express." In modern terms, proof theory has to be supplemented by model theory.

No need for proof theory since per Dummett, proof theory, if it has any meaning, is for use only, and concept scripting is really text scripting which belongs to the larger field of the Peircean semiotics or the contemporary ruliads aka sign processes not merely common symbolization via text or signs, in a similar fashion as Husserlian transcendental phenomenology's idealities vs mundane idealization...

Gödel, like Frege, described proof as "a sequence of thoughts convincing a sound mind." Generally, platonists and intuitionists hold that proofs in a formal system do not exhaust the concept (albeit for different reasons), but typically extensions are sought via 'new axioms' expressing 'intended models' rather than revising formal proof theory. However, their is some work on logic of informal provability inspired by Gödel's reflections on incompleteness, see Leitgeb, On Formal and Informal Provability.

@keshlam, I don't know why you think the symbol interpretation is more compact. It needs machinery that the concept version doesn't such as variable renaming and axiom schemas.

Many modern logicians would think that what you are describing would be a backwards step. Symbols are clearcut and straightforward things. Concepts, ideas, reasons and inferences are woolly and difficult to pin down. One of the main advances in our understanding of logic over the last 150 years has been to separate it from epistemology and psychology. My computer can manipulate symbols but it does not use concepts, ideas or reasons. The modern approach to logic provides rigour and even allows us to outsource logic to our computers.

There is Natural Logic. Summarising horribly, Natural Logic is logic without Aristotle's Law of the Excluded Middle, unless it is explicitly invoked. In normal logic, for any P and Q, Q belongs either to P or not-P. In Natural Logic, Q belongs to P, to not-P, or some other class that catches all the special states where assigning Q to one of the previous two classes is not valid.
This comes closer to Natural language. Is that last paragraph correct? It is written language: it is probably not wholly correct, nor wholly incorrect. Your interpretation of my words may not match what I meant. My interpretation may not match that of any particular dictionary. I have to ask "How do you define correct so there is no state other than correct and not-correct?"

Interesting. Thanks for the pointer.
